# Insert CSV data into distant MariaDB server with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, debian, mariadb, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to insert data into a remote MariaDB server.

I tried to tweak my code as much as possible following the other posts but it still not working.

Here is the check on my Debian/MariaDB server :

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

The CSV file content is :

```
"EMPLOYEE_ID","LAST_NAME"
"6762","name 1"
"6789","name 2"
"8234","name 3"
"7001","name 4"
"7623","name 5"
"6892","name 6"
"7040","name 7"
"5950","name 8"
"7032","name 9"
"4380","name 10"
```

On a Windows Server, I'm trying to execute the following on Powershell:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.18\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll")
$connexion = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$connexion.ConnectionString = "server=${servername};user id=${username};password=${password};database=${database};pooling=false;AllowLoadLocalInfile=true"
$connexion.Open()
$cmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$cmd.Connection = $connexion
$cmd.CommandText = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'SQL_Export.csv' INTO TABLE test_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '`"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';"
$query = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$connexion.Close()
```

And I keep getting the following error :

```
Exception lors de l'appel de « ExecuteNonQuery » avec « 0 » argument(s) : « Fatal error encountered during command execution. »
Au caractère C:\Users\easyvista\Desktop\test\csv_to_mysql.ps1:22 : 1
+ $query = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MySqlException
```

Further information :

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                   
PSVersion                      4.0                                                                                                                                                                                     
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                     
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                 
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                         
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.19170                                                                                                                                                                          
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                                                                                                                                    
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2     


Server version: 10.1.41-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.9
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
```

Comment: Does the query work if you print the CommandText and copy it into mysql command line client? The [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/load-data-infile/) got a comment claiming that _it seems you must have the ENCLOSED BY before the TERMINATED BY_.

Comment: It works on both orders in sql cli : LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/html/SQL_Export.csv' INTO TABLE test_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'; Query OK, 10 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec) Records: 10 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 0 Warnings: 1

Comment: What does `SHOW WARNINGS;` say _immediately_ after running that `LOAD`?

Comment: This seems strange:  '`"'

Comment: Nothing new with `SHOW WARNINGS;` still getting the same error,
I contourned this by sending the entire file to my linux server and scheduling a `LOAD` with crontab, but i kept the issue open for further propositions.